# multiselect dropdown sorts based on value present in option tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, multi-select

I am having a multiselect dropdown whose value are populated based on iteration through for each. However the order I am sending the data is not maintained. 
Please suggest what should I do.

```
<select id="secWhse" path="secondaryWarehouse" multiple="true" style="display: none;"
        title="Select the secondary warehouse to which you want to give access to the user.">
    <option value="1">Enterprise</option>
    <option value="14">enter2</option>
    <option value="17">enter3</option>
    <option value="19">4thenterprise</option>
</select>
```

But if I am able to print the value directly, Its printing in my order.

**UPDATE**: Plugin we are using is: http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/multiple-select/docs/#multiple-select
 CODE:

```
$('#secWhse').multipleSelect({  filter: true,multiple: true});
```

JSP code to populate select tag:
    
            
                  ${item.value}

Comment: Where is your JavaScript?

Comment: Can you specify the order in which you want it to be?

Comment: You will have to sort the data before populating the list.

Comment: why you want the order to be maintained? and also by `order`, do u mean the order in which is printed first?